# Can I zoom in/out without clearing my selection in MS Paint?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-paint

I have part of an image selected in Microsoft Paint in Windows 7.

[image: Selected section MS Paint]

I want to zoom in to my image and make precise adjustments. However, when I try to zoom in, either with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll Up</kbd> or the **Magnifier** tool, my current selection is cleared.

[image: Cleared selection after zooming in MS Paint]

**Is it possible to zoom in using Microsoft Paint *without* clearing my current selection?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw the selection box but DON'T lift up your mouse button while zooming in, you can stay in box selection mode. But if you've already made your selection and change the zoom, it will get rid of your selection.